# Giving System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. using datetime.ParseExact in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatexception

I am below code in c#, where I am converting my string type format date to datetime, but giving the error.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionDictionary.GetValue("UserDetails", "ExpiryDate")))
{
    DateTime ExpiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(SessionDictionary.GetValue("UserDetails", "ExpiryDate"), "dd mmm yy", null);                      
    strDate = sitedata.FormatDate(ExpiryDate, TridionDateFormat.ShortDate);
}
else
{
    strDate = "-";
}
```

My `SessionDictionary.GetValue("UserDetails", "ExpiryDate")` is string type data which returns "31/01/2011 00:00:00" format date, in above code where I am using `DateTime.ParseExact` it is giving me `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` error.

Please suggest what is wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample date you describe (31/01/2011 00:00:00) looks like a format dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss, so why are you using dd mmm yyyy?

Try

```
DateTime.ParseExact(..., "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note the use of HH (24-hour clock) rather than hh (12-hour clock), and the use of InvariantCulture because some cultures use separators other than slash.

For example, if the culture is de-DE, the format "dd/MM/yyyy" would expect period as a separator (31.01.2011).

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of *mmm*(there isn't such month format), try *MMM* instead.(looks like Feb/Jan/etc)

Comment: No that can't be issue as if I just use "d" in that is also giving the error, please suggest!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format to parse the date. The correct one is:

```
DateTime ExpiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(SessionDictionary.GetValue("UserDetails", "ExpiryDate"), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", null)
```

Also, if your system date format is set to `dd/MM/yyyy` you can simply use:

```
DateTime ExpiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(SessionDictionary.GetValue("UserDetails", "ExpiryDate"), "G", null)
```

Comment: I have tried this but still giving same error to me, please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Try
`DateTime ExpiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(SessionDictionary.GetValue("UserDetails", "ExpiryDate"), "g", null);`

or see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx